# How to make SwiftUI TabBar background always transparent

Tags: swiftui, tabbar

I am trying to completely remove the background of a TabView in SwiftUI, but I can't seem to find a solution.

I've implemented my own background to the TabView like this:

```
TabView {
    ZStack {
        DriveView()
        BackgroundTabBar()
    }.tabItem {
        Image("tab_drive")
        Text("Drive")
    }
}
```

And then:

```
init() {
    UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = .white
    UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
}
```

But, when I implement a ScrollView I get the default opaque background also:
[image: Tab Bar problem]

How do I get completely rid of the background in the TabBar, also when scrolling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find another solution where I was still able to control the appearance of the tab items using this:

```
init() {
    let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
    appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground() // <- HERE
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.iconColor = .white
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]

    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.iconColor = UIColor(Color.accentColor)
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(Color.accentColor)]

    UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .tabBar)` on the view you are presenting in the tab to control the tab bar visibility. The default is `.automatic` which makes the background visible when scroll bar content is behind it.

Comment: Awesome! This works perfectly, the background is gone! Thank you very much! But now it seems like this is no longer working: UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = .white

Comment: I'm not sure you get much control over the unselected colour, even with the new UIKit (standard / scroll edge appearance) APIs.

Comment: It seems like this could do it: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbaritemappearance

I just can figure out how to apply it yet.